# Using Radix UI props does not work in React JS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radix

In my react Js application i am using Radix. I need to customizze toast component changing the position where the component should appear.

For this, the API provides the next way:

```
<ToastProvider swipeDirection="up">
```

So `swipeDirection` is responsible for this.

**ISSUE**: Using the above changes, the component stil appear at the bottom even with changed prop.

 Question: How to make the component to appear at the top and why the prop does not work?
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/z688kv?module=App.js&file=/App.js:3909-3944

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is no "position" prop out of the box for this component. The `swipeDirection="up"` prop only specify that you can delete a toast by swiping it to the top. You can still specify where to place the toasts with pure css. Just update the styles of the `ToastViewport` component.

Default styles are:

```css
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
```

So to have the toasts in the top right corner for example just use:

```html
<ToastViewport style={{ top: "0px" }} />
```

[image: Edit dreamy-fermat-gr5vcj]

Comment: also is there a possibility to add these styles: `const slideIn = keyframes({
  from: { transform: `translateX(calc(100% + ${VIEWPORT_PADDING}px))` },
  to: { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
});` without using `stitches`, just simple css?

Comment: Of course this is just a js API to write a css @keyframes. You can still write it as css and use it in the `style` prop.

Comment: then how to add styles for `&[data-state="open"` and `&[data-state="closed"`? I tried with simple css but did not manage

Comment: i added this ` <ToastPrimitive.Root  style={{
        '&[data-swipe="open"]': {
          transform: 'translateX(var(--radix-toast-swipe-move-x))',
        },
      }}>` but it does not work. Could you help please?

Answer (score 2):

Adding on @johannchopin answer, if you want to position the toast to the left-bottom for example.

First, some changes to the `slideIn` animation:

```
const slideIn = keyframes({
  from: { transform: `translateX(calc(-100% + ${VIEWPORT_PADDING}px))` },
  to: { transform: "translateX(0)" }
});

const swipeOut = keyframes({
  from: { transform: "translateX(var(--radix-toast-swipe-move-y))" },
  to: { transform: `translateX(calc(-100% + ${VIEWPORT_PADDING}px))` }
});
```

notice the use of `-100%` instead of `100%`

and a small change to the `StyledViewport` default position:

```
const StyledViewport = styled(ToastPrimitive.Viewport, {
  position: "fixed",
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  //other styles removed to keep the code short
});
```

[image: Edit dreamy-fermat-gr5vcj]

Comment: the what is the purpose of swipeDirection="up" if we need to change styles?

Comment: it's the swipe direction to close the toast, if you see the example I provided when there is a toast you can close it by swiping the mouse cursor to the left